# Route traffic to IP/subnet over specific interface

Tags: windows, networking, routing, qemu

I have a setup with a server, which is hosting VMs and a samba share. One of those VMs is a Windows VM.
This VM has two network interfaces:

- Interface A (10.216.x.x): Connected to a network bridge which allows access to the LAN
- Interface B (192.168.100.x): Connected to an isolated network interface, which only allows connections to the server. This is a bridge interface with no physical bonds.

As interface B is a lot faster connecting to the host SMB than the interface B (Multiple GByte/sec vs 1Gbit/s), I want to use this network. To do this, I mapped a network drive to 192.168.100.1. This IP should only be usable through interface B, as it is a virtual and isolated network.

When trying to access the samba share, for some reason interface A is now used. This will saturate the physical 1GBit link on the server and throttle performance a lot. If I remove Interface A, the traffic is flowing through interface B as expected. But as I need Interface A for most tasks, I cannot remove it.

I now tried to force all traffic to 192.168.100.1 to flow through Interface B via routes. I added routes for 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.100.1/36 with a metric of 1 and an interface setting for interface B. This has been done with standard and persistent routes. Still, traffic to 192.168.100.1 will only flow though interface A.

Following is the routing table to verify the previous statements. Note that interface A has an IP of 10.216.0.67 and B has 192.168.100.186 and that IPv6 is disabled on both interfaces.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.216.0.1      10.216.0.67     15
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.100.1  192.168.100.186    271
       10.216.0.0      255.255.0.0          On-link       10.216.0.67    271
      10.216.0.67  255.255.255.255          On-link       10.216.0.67    271
   10.216.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link       10.216.0.67    271
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0          On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0          On-link   192.168.100.186    271
    192.168.100.1  255.255.255.255    192.168.100.1  192.168.100.186     16
  192.168.100.186  255.255.255.255          On-link   192.168.100.186    271
  192.168.100.255  255.255.255.255          On-link   192.168.100.186    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link       10.216.0.67    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link   192.168.100.186    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link       10.216.0.67    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link   192.168.100.186    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    192.168.100.1  255.255.255.255    192.168.100.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.100.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

I cannot see any reason for any 192.168.100.1 connection to go through interface A instead of B.

How can I force connections to 192.168.100.1 to use interface B instead of A in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that connections to 192.168.100.1 indeed use interface B, but the connection soon becomes *no longer "to 192.168.100.1"* as [SMB Multichannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn610980(v=ws.11)) kicks in.

(Perhaps the SMB client sees interface A as having a higher reported link rate than interface B, despite its actual speed? It wouldn't be surprising for VM interfaces, as they can't really report any useful physical link rate.)

Use Wireshark to verify this theory.

Try disabling multichannel using either of:

- on server, `Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableMultiChannel $false`;
- on client, `Set-SmbClientConfiguration -EnableMultiChannel $false`.

(Also, stop disabling IPv6.)

Comment: Thanks, this was it! As I am running linux, I needed to add ```server multi channel support = no``` to smb.conf on the server side.